# Java: Determining when a TCP Socket slows down and reestablish a connection

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending data from my system to third party systems using a persistent TCP Socket. It works fine but sometimes due to some bug in the third party system the connection slows down and it slows down my application.

How to catch this state? Should i just set a connection timeout? Because when this happens i need to close the existing socket and reestablish a new one after some period of time.

The code is as follows:

```
public static void initializeCongServer() throws Exception {
    try{
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(congestionDownStartTime!=null){
            long timeInSecs = (currentTime.getTimeInMillis() - congestionDownStartTime.getTimeInMillis())/1000;
            if(timeInSecs < config.getCongestionReconnectTimeInSecs()){
                logWrapper1.log(Level.DEBUG, "Packet not sent to Congestion as it was down when last checked. Connection to congestion will be retried again in: "+ (config.getCongestionReconnectTimeInSecs() - timeInSecs)+" seconds");
                return;
            }
        }
        if(congConnector!=null){
            congConnector.close();
            if(congConnector.sock!=null){
                congConnector.sock.close();
            }
            congConnector = null;
        }
        logWrapper1.log(Level.DEBUG, "Reconnecting with congestion server.");
        congConnector = new Connector(config.getCongServerIP(), config.getCongServerPort(), 1, 2);
        congConnector.connect();
        congestionDownStartTime = null;
    } catch(Exception e){
        congestionDownStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        logWrapper1.log(Level.DEBUG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void sendDataToCongServer(String data){
    try {
        System.out.println("CONGESTION: "+data);
        synchronized(Main.class){
            if(congConnector!=null && congConnector.connected==true){
                congConnector.send(data, false, false, 1);
            }else{
                initializeCongServer();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        congestionDownStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        logWrapper1.log(Level.DEBUG, "CONGESTION DOWN: "+data);
        logWrapper1.log(Level.DEBUG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

public class Connector {

String host = null;
int port = 0;
int index = 0;
long reconnectTime = 0;
Socket sock = null;
boolean connected = false;
InputStream inputStream = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

public Connector(String host, int port, int index, long reconnectTime) throws Exception {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.index = index;
    this.reconnectTime = reconnectTime;
}

public synchronized Socket reconnect() throws Exception {
    sock = new Socket(host, port);
    inputStream = sock.getInputStream();
    outputStream = sock.getOutputStream();
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
    connected = true;
    return sock;
}

public void close() {
    try {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


private synchronized void notifyWait() {
    connected = false;
}


public synchronized void connect() throws Exception {
    reconnect();
}

public void send(String str, boolean appendLine, boolean bindResult, int MedReadTimeOut) throws Exception {
    String result = null;
    if (connected == true) {
        try {
            byte[] b = null;
            if (appendLine == true) {
                b = (str + "\r\n").getBytes();
            } else {
                b = str.getBytes();
            }
            dataOutputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            notifyWait();
            connected = false;
            throw new Exception(ex);
        }
        if (bindResult == true) {
            try {
                sock.setSoTimeout(MedReadTimeOut);
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            } 
            catch (SocketTimeoutException sockEx) {
                String debugInfo = "TIMEOUT= "+MedReadTimeOut+".MEDIATION PORT CLOSED " + sock.getPort();
                System.out.println(debugInfo);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                notifyWait();
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Congestion Socket Closed.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you analyzed the network traffic so you're absolutely sure that it's the 3rd party application's fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection timeout won't help since it defines the maximum allowable time to *initiate* a connection. If anything, you might want to try [setSoTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) instead.

But generally speaking, catching such a situation using socket timeouts isn't optimal, as the socket won't time out for as long as some information arrives once in a while, even it's a single byte at a time.

For a more robust solution, I suggest solving the problem at the application level, not the socket level. Maybe use a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) to check the amount of data received/sent through the troublesome socket within a given timeframe (e.g. last 5 minutes), then reconnect if the average drops below a predefined threshold.